# How to see at what time an SMS was sent?

Tags: sms, date-and-time

My phone runs Marshmallow.

When I recieve an SMS, the messaging app only shows me the time at which the message was recieved locally on my phone. There are various circumstances in which this time can vary greatly from the time at which the message was sent by the sender, for example, if my phone was in airplane mode when the message was sent.

I know that this information is made available by my carrier, because there are phones out there that show when the message was sent.

How can I show this information on Android Marshmallow?

I've tried searching the web for this. I found an app that claims to do it, but it only works on Kit Kat and older. The rest of the results I trawled through were mostly forums with people discussing the issue. I did not see any of the posts present a working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download and install the application [Android Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) made by Google LLC.
This app replaces the standard Message app. To see the time an SMS/message was sent, just push and hold a finger on the message and press on the information icon that appears. In my case (OnePlus 5T, Android 8.0.0) I could even check messages that I had received before I got the app.

Source: [Android Forums - Text Messages ACTUAL Time Sent](https://androidforums.com/threads/text-messages-actual-time-sent.73270/page-2)

Comment: This worked for me. I'll note that my device now runs Nougat, and not Marshmallow like in OP. Also, the app mentioned in the answer is already the stock messaging app on my current phone. It was not on the Marshmallow device in OP, which was a Samsung device.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I use this app with my Google Pixel 3 phone. When I push and hold my finger on the message, I feel the phone vibrate as a response, but nothing appears. I'm relatively new to Android devices as I switched from an iPhone about 2 months ago. Is there something that could be preventing the information icon from appearing?

Comment: Aha! of course I figured it out seconds after commenting. Simply tapping (not holding) the message slides it up to reveal a timestamp.

Comment: I have an LG G5 running Android Oreo 8.0, and I use Android Messages. If I "View Details" on a received message, it tells me that both the Sent and Received times are the same, and that is the time the message was transferred to my phone, *not* the time it was sent. A friend sent me a message at 1 pm (confirmed via a screenshot). On my phone, View Details says the sent (and received) time was 3:50 pm. That's when I turned my phone on, and it retrieved the message.

Answer (score 1):

There's a messaging app called [Textra SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra). It allows you to see the time the message was sent. All you have to do is tap on a message (tap, not long press) and press the 'info' icon, and it will give you the details.

[image]

I am not sure where this app gets its information from and therefore I cannot vouch for its accuracy. I believe that you can only see the details for messages that you received after downloading Textra.

Comment: On my phone I only see recieved, not sent in Textra. Maybe my carrier doesn't provide this information after all?

Comment: @Revetahw Make sure you are checking this info for messages that came after you download textra. Messages that arrived before that, will not show sent time

Comment: Yes, I did it for messages recieved after installation.

Comment: @Revetahw strange indeed

Comment: Maybe the information is not provided by my particular carrier.

Answer (score 0):

[GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) provides you with the time the message was sent, but the free version has some ads. This is a helpful feature if your phone is off or in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the default messages app, hold down the message in question until it's highlighted, then touch the three dots in the upper right corner. Select "view details," and it will display both the time the message was sent and the time it was received.

Comment: By "default messages", I assume it's Android Messages by Google? Otherwise, might help to mention the device model, Android version, and if possible, the package name. Otherwise, this looks like the same to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193608/44325)

Answer (score 0):

On my LG Rebel (LGL44VL), I can open the message then touch and hold my finger on the screen and it will give an option for "Details." This includes time sent as well as time received.

Answer (score -1):

Set Samsung Messenger as your default messaging app. It has the date above the messages.

[image]

Comment: Just to add that this app is only available on Samsung devices.

Comment: In the screenshot it doesn't show time sent.